# adding interests with check_boxes to user profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

so I have an app that allows users to chose their interests by clicking checkboxes which then add the selected interests to the users profile page.

I'm not quite sure I understand this well enough to implement it though, my idea is to add an interests column to the users table in string format. And then populate the interests myself in the database and then put click boxes on the user edit page and which ever interests are clicked will be added.

I know this sounds totally off, and that's probably because it is - so what's the best way to do this?

So far I've populated interests field with some seed data and added this code to edit page and here's the error:

```
undefined method `merge' for "Soccer":String
Extracted source:

    <div><%= f.input_field :occupation, placeholder: "Your occupation",  autocomplete: :off %></div>

    Interests: 
    <div><%= f.check_box "interests", "Soccer" %></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to create a model called `interest`, this should create a migration for you. You will then be able to create as many interests as you would like to display. You are then going to want to create a database table called `interests_users`, assuming the users model is indeed called `user`.

At this point, you can tell both the `user` and the `interests` model that they `has_and_belongs_to_many` of the other model.

[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) is some simple documentation on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

second parameter is for options hash and third parameter is for value Try this
`<%= f.check_box "interests",{}, "Soccer" %>`
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box